# Python joining current directory and parent directory with os.path.join

Tags: python, os.path

I want to do join the current directory path and a relative directory path `goal_dir` somewhere up in the directory tree, so I get the absolute path to the `goal_dir`. This is my attempt:

```
import os
goal_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../../my_dir")
```

Now, if the current directory is `C:/here/I/am/`, it joins them as `C:/here/I/am/../../my_dir`, but what I want is `C:/here/my_dir`. It seems that `os.path.join` is not that intelligent.

How can I do this?

Comment: Remember that `os.getcwd()` gets where you're executing the script from, while `os.path.dirname(__file__)` gets where the Python file is.  Be sure to use the correct one for your application!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lately, I discovered pathlib.

```
from pathlib import Path
cwd = Path.cwd()
goal_dir = cwd.parent.parent / "my_dir"
```

Or, using the file of the current script:

```
cwd = Path(__file__).parent
goal_dir = cwd.parent.parent / "my_dir"
```

In both cases, the absolute path in simplified form can be found like this:

```
goal_dir = goal_dir.resolve()
```

Comment: What about Linux environment folders?

Comment: @InfiniteLoops What about them? They're good! And you can access them using `os.environ[var]` or `os.getenv(var)`. I think `pathlib` doesn't access them.

Comment: i have a py script that I'm working right now and Im not sure if the directory location being state correctly. Cause when I try to run it on Collab, it says File or Directory not found.

Comment: Colab is a different story. I recommend that you ask a new question (or try looking it up first).

Answer (score 58):

You can use [normpath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath), [realpath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) or [abspath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

```
import os
goal_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../../my_dir")
print goal_dir  # prints C:/here/I/am/../../my_dir
print os.path.normpath(goal_dir)  # prints C:/here/my_dir
print os.path.realpath(goal_dir)  # prints C:/here/my_dir
print os.path.abspath(goal_dir)  # prints C:/here/my_dir
```

Answer (score 11):

consider to use `os.path.abspath` this will evaluate the absolute path

or One can use `os.path.normpath` this will return the normalized path (Normalize path, eliminating double slashes, etc.)

One should pick one of these functions depending on requirements

In the case of `abspath` In Your example, You don't need to use `os.path.join`

```
os.path.abspath("../../my_dir")
```

`os.path.normpath` should be used if you are interested in the relative path.

```
>>> os.path.normpath("../my_dir/../my_dir")
'../my_dir'
```

Other references for handling with file paths:

- [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) - Object-oriented filesystem paths
- [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?#module-os.path)— Common pathname manipulations