# Accessing file with ../../

Tags: python, filepath

I can extract a string from a .json file:
path1 --> `"../../Images/PatientID 0/1.2.840.113704.1.111.2716.1398172953.1/1.2.840.113704.1.111.2716.1398173172.21"`

The `Images` folder above is in path2 --> `D:\\\\CAP Exam Data\` path(windows).
I want to remove the `../../` part and join path1 and path2 to access the file from a python script.

I have tried the following:

```
path1 = '../../Images/PatientID 0/1.2.840.113704.1.111.2716.1398172953.1/1.2.840.113704.1.111.2716.1398173172.21' 
path2 =  ''D:\\\\CAP Exam Data\

newpath  = os.path.join(path2, path1)
print(newpath)
```

`D:\\CAP Exam Data\../../Images/9111142/1.2.840.113745.101000.100100.2.41057.5995.9117440/1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.60044.30000012053010493246800022943`

Now how do I remove `../../` part? I tried slicing like `[4:]` in path1.
But nothing seems to work.

Also, how can I fix up the `/` `\` windows, Linux conflict? Is it even an issue?

Comment: "Also, how can I fix up the / \ windows, Linux conflict?" Python takes care of that. ``/`` can be used as a system independent separator.

Comment: see: [Python joining current directory and parent directory with os.path.join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295086/python-joining-current-directory-and-parent-directory-with-os-path-join)

Comment: You need to join path2+path1, not path1+path2,

Comment: The easiest way to work with Windows filenames in Python strings is to use raw strings that don't treat \ as an escape, like this: `r"D:\CAP Exam Data"`. And the most friendly module for working with paths is `pathlib`.

Comment: @azro good call, i actually did what you said but wrote it here reversed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newpath.replace('\../../', '/')`

This worked.

`D:\\CAP Exam Data/Images/9111142/1.2.840.113745.101000.100100.2.41057.5995.9117440/1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.60044.30000012053010493246800022943`